# Reading from a smartcard using nfc on android

Tags: android, nfc

I would like to ask an nfc related question for the android!

Firstly, I have created a java application to read my company's staff pass using java smartcardio api. I did it by sending an APDU command and parse the response APDU.

Now, I need to use the NFC on an android phone to read the staff pass. I used an nfc reader from the market to read my staff pass and found out that it is a mifare classic 1k card. The reader also showed me the the data in HEX for all 16 sectors. Apparently the HEX data is very different from the HEX data i got when I was using smartcardio api in java. Am I looking for the data in the wrong location? Can someone guide me to how I should proceed doing this? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Your staff pass probably contains and NFC chip that can do both [`IsoDep`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/IsoDep.html) and [`MifareClassic`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/MifareClassic.html). You can find out exactly which ones are supported by the tag by calling [`getTechList()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/Tag.html#getTechList%28%29) on the `Tag` object in the NFC intent.

In your app, you can access both `IsoDep` and `MifareClassic`, but not at the same time (call `close()` first before switching to another technology). `IsoDep` is the technology where you can use APDU commands in the `transceive()` method.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am able to get the data that I want by accessing IsoDep and using the transceive() method. Basically i used the same commands as i did for the RFID reader and it worked! =)